# Alguien podria ayudarme a encontrar el error?

Tags: php

Cuando quiero correr mi código me aparece este error:

> Use of undefined constant  - assumed ''

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
   {
        $email=$request['email'];
        $first_name=$request['first_name'];
        $password=bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis tras el cierre del último corchete (un carácter `fe ff`). Por favor, elimina el carácter adicional y te funcionará.

Comment: No todos los editores te permiten ver caracteres no visibles. En cuanto he pegado el código dentro de VIM me ha mostrado la secuencia no visible. Inicialmente iba a usar `hexdump` para comprobar que no habías usado algún "guión bonito" en vez de guión normal o un espacio irrompible (por usar un editor de texto enriquecido).

Comment: ¿Se ha solucionado tu problema tras hacer lo que te indiqué?

Comment: @fedorqui , en tu edición has eliminado el carácter que provoca el problema. Voy a reponerlo en su lugar. Edito: parece que no es posible restablecer (al menos desde chrome) los caracteres que provocan el error.

Comment: Lo sé @fedorqui, lo usé antes si recuerdas (cuando la edición). La otra respuesta no era importante, por eso no te nombré. PD: Mike3911, por favor, comprueba si se arregló tu problema. Gracias.

Comment: Como referencia: deshice los cambios pues cada vez el navegador eliminaba el carácter en cuestión.

Comment: Saludos  OscarGarcia
Disculpa la tardanza amigo, remplace mi código y funciono a la perfección te agradezco mucho la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un problema con un [BOM *little endian* UTF-16](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes) que has desplazado hasta el final del script.

Eso provoca un error de sintaxis tras el cierre del último corchete (un carácter `fe ff` que corresponde al BOM desplazado) que trata de interpretar como constante y convierte en cadena.

Eliminando el carácter se soluciona el problema. Si tu editor no muestra caracteres no visibles puedes borrar la línea completa (seleccionando desde la línea anterior hasta la posterior) reescribiéndola de nuevo posteriormente.

Aquí tienes el código corregido para que copies y pegues de vuelta a un archivo vacío:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
   {
        $email=$request['email'];
        $first_name=$request['first_name'];
        $password=bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

    }
 }
?>
```

El problema es que probablemente creaste el documento con un editor que generó el BOM al comienzo del archivo y luego lo abriste con otro diferente y lo fuiste desplazando de manera silenciosa (y aparentemente invisible) hasta ese lugar.